# content_main.xml is not generated in my android project with BasicActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

When I am adding BasicActivity android studio created 2 files (activity and content) and was working fine.

Yesterday I changed my package name using refactor. Then after problem starts.

Now when I am creating an activity using basic activity only activity is created. (content is not created)

How to solve this ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.
Adarsh

Comment: You should check applicationId in app build  .

Comment: Can you please help which attribute I should check ?

Comment: applicatinid is my package name

Comment: I have also done clean and rebuild... Still not solved.. please help me

Comment: I am still waiting for anwer.. if anyone has any idea.. .please help me.